# Map returns lists instead of dates

Tags: r, purrr

I have a tibble column containing dates, and I want to match them to the nearest higher date in a list of dates. Therefore I wrote a function `matchDate`, which I want to call with `map`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d1 = as.Date("2022-01-01")
d2 = as.Date("2022-12-31")

matchDate = function(date,matchDates,...){
  matchDates[matchDates >= date] %>% min %>% return
}

df = tibble(date = seq.Date(from=d1,to=d2,by='months'))
dates = seq.Date(from=d2,to=d1,by='-3 months')
df$match = map(df$date,~matchDate(.x,matchDates=dates))

typeof(matchDate(d1,dates))
#> [1] "double"

df
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    date       match     
#>    <date>     <list>    
#>  1 2022-01-01 <date [1]>
#>  2 2022-02-01 <date [1]>
#>  3 2022-03-01 <date [1]>
#>  4 2022-04-01 <date [1]>
#>  5 2022-05-01 <date [1]>
#>  6 2022-06-01 <date [1]>
#>  ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Not sure why `typeof` returns `double` here, but the function works fine and `map` also returns the right dates. The only thing is, it wrappes them into a list (of length one). I tried to add `unlist` at different places in my code, but it didn't change anything. Can someone explain what is going on, or how to unlist correctly? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may flatten it- by default `map` returns a `list` if we don't specify the suffix for column types i.e. `_int`, `_dbl` `_chr` etc to return a `vector`.  With `Date` class it is a bit complicated as the storage mode is integer/double and this could coerce to its integer storage values

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df$match <- map(df$date,~matchDate(.x,matchDates=dates)) %>% 
     invoke(c,.)
```

-output

```
> df
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   date       match     
   <date>     <date>    
 1 2022-01-01 2022-03-31
 2 2022-02-01 2022-03-31
 3 2022-03-01 2022-03-31
 4 2022-04-01 2022-07-01
 5 2022-05-01 2022-07-01
 6 2022-06-01 2022-07-01
 7 2022-07-01 2022-07-01
 8 2022-08-01 2022-10-01
 9 2022-09-01 2022-10-01
10 2022-10-01 2022-10-01
11 2022-11-01 2022-12-31
12 2022-12-01 2022-12-31
```

---

With `base R`, we can use `do.call` with `c`

```
do.call("c", map(df$date,~matchDate(.x,matchDates=dates)))
 [1] "2022-03-31" "2022-03-31" "2022-03-31" "2022-07-01" "2022-07-01" "2022-07-01" "2022-07-01" "2022-10-01" "2022-10-01" "2022-10-01"
[11] "2022-12-31" "2022-12-31"
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed that works. Why can't we just use ```c(map(df$date,~matchDate(.x,matchDates=dates)))``` instead of ```do.Call```?

Comment: @Yann `map` is a `list`, by wrapping with `c` it just appends another element to the list.  Here, there was no argument, so ti does nothing.  You can use `c(df$match[1], df$match[2],...)` (based on the match column in your post.  It is a variadic argument (`...`), thus we use `do.call`